# Login TYPO3 6.1 not possible

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.1.x

I have to manage a realy old TYPO3 Vers (6.1.9)
I can't login in the BE with any available user
Trying to generate a new one via the install tool I get this error:

User not created
Error: Field 'TSconfig' doesn't have a default value

I have tried to generate a new user via phpmyadmin - no login possible :-(

the hosting server use mariaDB/mysql and PHP 5.6

Comment: provide source code and error message~

Answer (score 1):

Your error message leads to a MariaDB failure, as the field TSconfig in be_users has no default defined. You can fix this manually in your PhpMyAdmin by the following SQL command:

```
ALTER TABLE be_users
ALTER TSconfig SET DEFAULT '';
```

After this executing you should be able to create a new backend user via InstallTool.

Comment: thanks a lot
that worked but I'm still not able to login …
even with this new generated user

Comment: Okay, is rsa auth activated for backend login and is password saved in plain or encrypted in database?

Comment: Did you check if the quota of your webspace is exceeded?

Comment: Did you check the cookie domain as well?

Comment: rsa: i am not shure but in the localconfiguration i find no rsa

quata is not exceeded

Comment: my hoster told me: Alternatively, you could manually set the "sql_mode" variable to "NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION" at the beginning of the connection to the database | seting this comand via phpmyadmin doesn't fit this